# Crontab is running command 3 times each run

Tags: linux, cron, redhat, rhel

I have the following crontab set up on a RHEL server ...

```
MAILTO=me@mydomain.com
*/2 * * * * wget --spider -q http://mydomain.com/cronjobs/importxml.php
```

As you can see this should run every 2 minutes, which it does, but it runs the command three times and I can't figure out why.

If I run

```
tail /var/log/cron
```

I get the following

```
Dec 12 13:56:01 msvsc02-g283nc crond[1431]: (root) RELOAD (cron/root)
Dec 12 13:56:01 msvsc02-g283nc crond[3224]: (root) CMD (wget --spider -q http://mydomain.com/cronjobs/importxml.php)
Dec 12 13:56:01 msvsc02-g283nc crond[2504]: (root) RELOAD (cron/root)
Dec 12 13:56:01 msvsc02-g283nc crond[3226]: (root) CMD (wget --spider -q http://mydomain.com/cronjobs/importxml.php)
Dec 12 13:56:01 msvsc02-g283nc crond[2472]: (root) RELOAD (cron/root)
Dec 12 13:56:01 msvsc02-g283nc crond[3228]: (root) CMD (wget --spider -q http://mydomain.com/cronjobs/importxml.php)
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have more than one cron process running in that server. This normally wont happen. But anyway confirm it with

```
 ps aux | grep cron
```

You can stop it by,

```
/etc/init.d/cron stop
```

or

```
service cron stop
```

or use 'kill PID' ( not recommended ).

And to start use start - instead of stop in either of above two commands.

Comment: You may be right...

   `root      1431  0.0  0.0   5376  1108 ?        Ss   11:58   0:00 crond restart
    root      2472  0.0  0.0   5376  1108 ?        Ss   Nov14   0:00 crond
    root      2504  0.0  0.0   5380  1112 ?        Ss   13:11   0:00 crond restart
    root      3908  0.0  0.0   5384  1108 ?        Ss   14:14   0:00 crond restart
    root      4457  0.0  0.0   4020   696 pts/1    S+   14:53   0:00 grep cron`

Comment: So how do I stop that happening?